# Sonar Taint analysis : javasecurity:S5131 : Forcing sanitization for Java Enums :

Tags: enums, sonarqube, taint

I have a Rest API developed in Java. I am using Enums as my request parameters lets say Gender is one of the Enum and say possible values of Gender are M,F
I understand that requestParametrs are user controlled.Sonar is complaining that it is tainted and I need to sanitize the input.

I am failing to understand how an Enum can be tainted and why its posing a risk. We can’t pass any random values to an Enum.

Looking forward to your suggestions.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> answers(
                      @RequestParam(value = "genderId", required = true) 
                      GenderEnum genderId) { // genderID is tainted as its controlled by User input


 SomeObject param = new SomeObject();
 param.setGenderId(genderId); //Polluted too, as requestParam is not sanitized

 //Lets assume you make some call to DB
  String result=dbCall(genderId);   //This is tainted too

   return "Hello"+genderId; //Result is also tainted as its also using Non-santized input

}
```

any wrong values to Enum will give you **HTTP 400 Bad Request** which is perfectly fine.

[I have asked the same question in sonarForum](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/javasecurity-s5131-reported-for-java-enums/26238/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above Enum issue will be fixed in a future release of sonar. I will comment here once I get more information.

[Enum issue - Reply from Sonarsource](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/javasecurity-s5131-reported-for-java-enums/26238/5)